# PHP compare array values if have same string

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, compare

I've a situation with two array. I want to compare a string in to array only if **status => active**  in two array show member if status is not active one from array ignore member.

```
$args_1 = array(
                **'status' => 'active',** // only if also active in $args_2
                'number' => 'all',
                'object_id' => array(2)
            );
            $args_2 = array(
                **'status' => 'active',** // only if also active in $args_1
                'number' => 'all',
                'object_id' => array(3)
            );
$member  = et_member( $args_1, $args_2 );       
            // User Loop
            if ( ! empty( $member ) ) {
...........
```

Just for share: I've tried with

```
if(isset($args_1['status']) && $args_2['status'] == 'active') // but doesn't work
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why are the `**` there?

Answer (score 0):

`if(isset($args_1['status']) && $args_2['status'] == 'active')` is not what you want so thats why it fails (although given your data it should succeed, even tho incorrect). You need to check for the existence of *both* keys then run a condition on their values.

E.g.

```js
$args_1 = array(
 'status' => 'active', // only if also active in $args_2
 'number' => 'all',
 'object_id' => array(2)
);

$args_2 = array(
 'status' => 'active', // only if also active in $args_1
 'number' => 'all',
 'object_id' => array(3)
);
   
if (isset($args_1["status"])  && isset($args_2["status"]) && $args_1["status"] == "active" && $args_2["status"] == "active") {
 
 echo "success";
}
else {

 echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've added a new comments please have check below.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your feedback.

I've tried but doesn't work , controlled only $args_1

```
$args_1 = status active 
$args_2 = status pending
Member showed in list in. So $args_2 is in pending.

$args_1 = status pending
$args_2 - status active
Member not showed in list because $args_1 is pending
```

So this controlled only $args_1 if is active, doesn't check if in both array have same values 'active'

I want to show only when $args_1 and $args_2 have status active if one from $args have status inactive most ignore this member

Thanks again

Comment: You should add this to your original question and not as an answer to your own question. In other words, providing *additional* details to a problem that was not forthcoming to begin with, should go in your original post. After all SO is not a game show. If you feel you stated the problem wrong then it would be helpful to update your question.